# Can somebody explain a code fragment (batch file)

Tags: batch-file

Iam still new to batch files i would appreciate it if somebody could explain this code fragment and what it does and how it can be used

`for /f "delims=" %%x in (config.txt) do (set "%%x")`

thank you for your help it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading a text file "config.txt" using a for loop. %%x is the place holder for whatever you are iterating over from the "config.txt". This is probably for reading values/variables from a config file. In simple terms, open config.txt, reads values using a for loop, set those values to a place holder "%%x", then do something with those values.